Gravitational collapse - proof that energy dissipation is required?
As an undergraduate, I took a short course on astrophysics, where I encountered the Jeans mass. This is the critical mass for a spherical cloud of interstellar gas above which the cloud is predicted to undergo gravitational collapse. At the time, I was happy enough with the fact that I could derive the Jeans mass by considering the average kinetic energy of a gas particle $3k_{B}T/2$ ($k_{B}$ being Boltzmann's constant) sitting on the edge of a spherical cloud with absolute temperature $T$ and asking whether it had enough energy to escape the cloud's gravitational potential. If not, then according to the arguments I was reading, the cloud would collapse.
However, it occurred to me later that no such collapse should happen unless the cloud also lost energy to its environment. Consider this simplified picture: As a typical particle on the edge of the cloud is accelerated towards the centre of mass of the nebula, its potential energy is converted to kinetic energy. If this energy is not lost, it will have sufficient energy to get to the outer edge again. Moreover, since it will be moving fastest near the centre of the cloud, it should spend most of its time around the edges, meaning that the average density of the cloud would not increase towards its centre.
Of course, we would never expect this happen in practice. Particles will collide with one another and dissipate energy through the emission of radiation. Just as a ball bearing rolling in a bowl eventually settles at the bottom of the bowl, so density of particles will increase towards the centre of the cloud. However, this involves a loss of energy to the environment and hence an overall increase in the entropy of the Universe. This crucial detail always seems to be missing from discussions of the Jeans mass and gravitational collapse.
I was wondering if there are any nice, simplified models of this that can be easily expressed? Quite possibly related to the entropy increase? It seems to me that this is an essential aspect of gravitational collapse that is more often than not glossed over. I imagine there ought to be some straight-forward thermodynamic argument proving energy loss is required for gravitational collapse.

This is a known fact. If there is only the gravitational interaction alone, no electromagnetic, no weak nor strong interactions, then gravitational collapse cannot happen, in both quantum and classical physics. You need at least one other interaction for the collapse to happen.

So are there any simple mathematical proofs of this? I imagine a thermodynamic argument involving the first and second laws maybe?

Sorry, it has been a really long while since I looked that up. But at least I know of its existence.

The virial theorem tells us that for an isolated cloud (no external pressure, magnetic fields or rotation) that
$$2K + \Omega = 0\ , $$
where $K$ is the kinetic energy of the cloud particles and $\Omega$ is the gravitational potential energy.
At the same time, the total energy of the cloud
$$ E = K + \Omega $$
and thus
$$E = \Omega/2$$
If you want to make the cloud more compact, then $\Delta \Omega$ is negative and therefore so must be $\Delta E$.
